# AdminUI Display of Groups is Cluttered - How can we improve?

Tags: groups, formbuilder, admin, ui

AdminUI comes bundled with CiviCRM - when enabled, it does a pretty great job on most pages - but on groups - I hate it. (I do like the search functionality though)

- It ignores hierarchy (parents, sub parents, children, etc) are all mixed in together - We have about 20 active parent groups at any given time - with maybe 100 active groups total. Parent groups are helpful to be organized or to see all related groups in one place.
- When searching for parent groups - it searches for all groups - not just ones listed as parents (or those that have "children"). Users have to remember the exact name of the parent group.
- <s>It breaks breadcrumbs. *CiviCRM > CiviCRM > FormBuilder > Edit Form > Manage Groups* - though this seems to be an issue throughout AdminUI. TBH the original breadcrumb wasnt that useful anyways, (it was just *CiviCRM*) but at least it wasn't misleading.</s>

Comment: FYI the breadcrumb issue was fixed a couple releases back. Which version of Civi are you using?

Comment: 5.65.1 - updating now to 5.69.1
Do core extensions only update with civicrm updates?

Comment: Yes, that's right, because the core extensions are bundled with core that's the only way to update them.

Comment: Regarding the second point, adding a filter to search only for parent or children should be doable but I think it currently behave the same as the legacy manage group page. The parent autocomplete filter is meant to get all groups which are children of the given parent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that we need hierarchical display but it's not yet possible in SearchKit.

However, if you prefer the old implementation, it's quite easy to disable the new one (and keeping AdminUI) by changing the page route (url) of the corresponding FormBuilder :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great! That's why we created AdminUI rather than putting things directly into core - so you can kick the tyres and we can improve the new searches before they replace core functionality.

Many setups don't use parent/child groups at all.  For others such as yours, they are a significant feature.

There are a couple of ways you can help:

1. Ideally, install a copy of master (so you have the latest SearchKit/FormBuilder/AdminUI), make changes to the Groups search and create a PR.
2. If you don't want to create a PR yourself, see the notes at the top of the [AdminUI tracking issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3912)
3. If you can't get implement the changes you'd like to see then [create a gitlab issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new) and describe how you think it should work. It is more useful to specify positively what it should do rather than just "It's a mess":-).  Note that we don't have expanding hierarchy functionality yet so things we can implement with its current abilities are more likely to happen soon.